# Bijections between $ℝ$ and an interval of the form $(1-δ,1+δ)$ for $δ>0$ is a real number

Tags: real-analysis

I know that there is some bijections between the open unit interval $(0,1)$ and $ℝ$. My **question** is about the existence of bijections between $ℝ$ and an interval of the form $(1-δ,1+δ)$ for $δ>0$ is a real number.

Comment: Can you find a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(1-\delta,1+\delta)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{2 \delta \arctan x}{\pi} + 1$?

Comment: @ Umberto P. Why you add the coefficient $π$.

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to find a bijection $f : (1-\delta,1+\delta) \to (0,1)$, and compose it with the bijection you know from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Just take the linear map
$$
f(x) = \frac{x-(1-\delta)}{2 \delta}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\left(0,1\right)$ be a bijection.

Then $\psi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\left(0,2\delta\right)$ prescribed
by $x\mapsto2\delta\phi\left(x\right)$ is a bijection .

Finally $\theta:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\left(1-\delta,1+\delta\right)$
prescribed by $x\mapsto\psi\left(x\right)+1-\delta$ is a bijection.